# Load DLL file and Call Functions in Python

Tags: c#, python, dll, ctypes

I have the problem loading the DLL file and calling the functions in Python.
I have tried a lot of tutorials, but still can't figure out how it works.
This is my class to export as DLL file. I use simple C# code.

```
namespace DemoClassLib
{
    public class cLib
    {
        public int increment(int x)
        {
            return x + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

After building the C# code, I get the DLL file called "DemoClassLib.dll".
I use ctypes to load the DLL file. Everything is okay until now.

```
from ctypes import *
myDll = WinDLL('D:\\Resources\\DemoClassLib\\bin\\Debug\\DemoClassLib.dll')
```

Starting from that point, I can't continue.
All the commands I have tried are failed.

```
n = c_int(1)
myDll.increment(n)
```

It keeps on showing me the errors.
How can I call the method "increment()" in Python?
And how can I pass the input and retrieve the output from that?
I am very new to Python.
Can someone help me please?
I would be very appreciated if you can provide me the source code tutorial.

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718088/using-ctypes-in-python-to-acces-a-c-sharp-dlls-methods), you cannot access a .NET library with `ctypes`. But an alternative way could be to [expose your library as a COM object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zsfww439.aspx) and [access it with win32com](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with ctypes because there is no symbol in the binary called simply "increment", as your increment method is a member of a class.  Even if this were C++ the name would be mangled.  But with C# you don't even get a mangled name in the symbol table because the code is interpreted by the .NET framework.

If you must for some reason interface with a C# library you may want to consider trying IronPython (http://ironpython.net/) which is Python running on the .NET framework with full access to the CLR.  The comment above suggesting exposing a COM interface could also work.