# Using ctypes in python to acces a C# dll's method from instance

Tags: c#, python, dllexport

i tried to test the examples from the [website](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) but the second one won't work.. i need to create instances and call the methods from the class where the instance is from. The first example is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718088/using-ctypes-in-python-to-acces-a-c-sharp-dlls-methods/31474688#31474688).

It seems I don't get the right python code :/ to reach the method and attribute behind pointer object..

This is the c# dll

```
[ComVisible(true)] 
[Guid("0000000a-000b-000c-0001-020304050607"), 
 InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface ISample
{
   // without MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr), .Net will marshal these strings as single-byte Ansi!
   // BStr is equivalent to Delphi's WideString
   String Name
   {
     // this is how to add attributes to a getter's result parameter
     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
     get;
     // this is how to add attributes to a setter's value parameter
     [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
     set;
   }

   int DoSomething(int value);
}

public class Sample : ISample
{
   public String Name{ get; set; }

   public int DoSomething(int value)
   {
     return value + 1;
   }
}

static class Exports
{
   [DllExport]
   public static void CreateSampleInstance([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]out ISample instance)
   {
     instance = new Sample{ Name = "Test" };
   }
}`enter code here`
```

i tried in python shell

```
>>>import ctypes
>>>a=ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(source)
>>>b=a.CreateSampleInstance
>>>b
<_FuncPtr object at 0x028E65D0>

>>>b.Name 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#85>", line 1, in <module>
    instance.Name
AttributeError: '_FuncPtr' object has no attribute 'Name'
```

Sure the pointer can't know the method DoSomething and the attribute Name, but how i can reach them :/

Comment: If you typed it in exactly the way you wrote in your question it's quite simple: `b.DoSomethink` != `b.DoSomething`

Comment: just typing ... i correct it .

Comment: Well for starters b is a function pointer and, therefore, callable via ctypes so something like `b()` is more appropriate. I'd suggest you export something more straight forward like the example here https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports#TOC-Basic-sample which sees two int's added together and the result returned.

Comment: thx for your hint, i will try it the next day. Your link is the same as the one in my header which worked well for me, but not enough. Thx again, i tried a lot because i did't find documentation about it (Python thing)

Comment: b.Name() is not working and b.DoSomething(1) also.
Both times: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File"<pyshell#2>",line 1, in <module>
      b.DoSomething(1)
AttributeError: '_FuncPtr' object has no attribute 'DoSomething'

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you take a look a IronPython (http://ironpython.net/) and specifically take a look at http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#id31

Comment: i have a big project in python 3.1 written. I can't switch to iron python because of the tkinter links. The author from the website wrote: 'btw, this is also how to pass objects between native and .Net ;-) ' so i just try to find the right python snipped