# Calling a .Net library in python?

Tags: python, .net, ctypes

Hi I am trying to send commands from python to a New Focus Picomotor controller. 
The commands for the controller are supposedly stored in a .dll library which I have. Is there a way to load this library and call the functions within it?

I am supposed to first initialise the controller to start communication. Which involves calling the function 'CmdLib8742'

I am given a list of the CmdLib Api, which gives a list of constructors and methods that are supposedly called by an language that can support calling a function from within a .NET library.

I know I am supposed to use ctypes. But multiple solutions listed on overflow seem to give me an error saying "Attribute error, function not found"

This is an example of the first two.

```
/// <summary>         
/// Constructor.         
/// </summary>       

public CmdLib8742 () 

/// < summary >         
/// Constructor.         
/// < /summary >         
/// < param name="logging" >True to request logging, otherwise false.< /param >         
/// < param name="msecDelayForDiscovery" >The number of milliseconds to wait for devices to be discovered.< /param >         
/// < param name="deviceKey" >The first device in the list of open instruments (null = none found).< /param >       

public CmdLib8742 (bool logging, int msecDelayForDiscovery, ref string deviceKey)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ctypes in python to access a C# dll's methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718088/using-ctypes-in-python-to-access-a-c-sharp-dlls-methods)

Comment: Have you found something? I have the same problem with these libraries from Newport. All the answers I find here, as the one by Neitsa, don't work that simply.