# Using NuGet and ctypes, trying to use c# dll library in python code. Unable to recognize functions

Tags: python, c#, ctypes, dllexport

I am using NuGet and ctypes to import a c# dll in my python code so that I can call the c# functions in python. However, for some reason when I try to call the c# functions, they are not recognized. (This is a test case)

C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

class Test
{
     public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        return  2;
    }


    [DllExport("add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static int TestExport(int left, int right)
    {
        return left + right;
    }

    public static int add2(int left, int right) {
        return left + right;
    }
}
```

Python Code:

```
import ctypes
a = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('bin/Debug/net6.0/app.dll')
print(a.add(2, 3))
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: function 'add' not found
```

Comment: Where is `DllExportAttribute` taken from?  Is it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29855666) by [Rob Deary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1977538/rob-deary) to [Using ctypes in python to access a C# dll's methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6718088)?

Comment: The functions need to be exported following the *C* interface (they must be callable from *C*), which I doubt it's the case.